# How to find a full node in a recursive SQL query

Tags: sql, recursive-query

I would like to get the full nodes from existing recursive category tree, if the products table has a matching category.

I have the following.

```
WITH ret AS (
        SELECT  ID, ParentID, ProductCategoryId, ProductCategoryName
        FROM    ProductCategoryTree as p1, Products as p2 
        WHERE   p1.ProductCategoryId = p2.ProductCategoryId
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  p.ID, p.ParentID, p.ProductCategoryId, p.ProductCategoryName
        FROM    ProductCategoryTree as p INNER JOIN
                ret r ON p.ParentID = r.ID
      )
SELECT DISTINCT ID, ParentID, ProductCategoryId, ProductCategoryName
FROM ret;
```

This will give me the category of the product and all the child nodes of that category, but I would also need to get the category (or categories) from the upper level(s).

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Which database do you use? What happens when you inverse the parent-child relation on the last join: `ret r ON p.ID = r.ParentID` ?

Comment: Hi Tamas, it is SQL Server. I tested your suggestion, and after first tests, I think that did the trick! So Simple, yet effective :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments, you just reverse the parent-child relation on the last row of the join, and it will work:

```
ret r ON p.ParentID = r.ID
```